# Isomorphism of group between $\mathbb D_6$ (dihedral group) and GL

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $\mathbb D_6=\{e,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b : a^3=b^2=e\,\, \text{and}\,\, ba=a^2b\}$ and $GL =\{A \in{\rm Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z}_2) : A\text{ is invertible} \}$

Prove that  $\mathbb D_6$ and $GL$ are isomorphic (group).

**My attempt:**
To prove that $\mathbb D_6$ and $GL$ are isomorphic we need to find a function $f$ such that is a bijection and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b\in GL$

Note that $GL = \{ \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\}$

Let $f:GL\rightarrow\mathbb{D}_6$ such that

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow e$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow a$

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow a^2$

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow b$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow ab$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow a^2b$

Note that by construction, $f$ is bijective. How can i prove that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$?  Not in the manual way, as I do not want to make $6!$ combinations.

Comment: Obviously $a,b$ are the generators of $\mathbb{D}_6$, so it suffices to show $\psi(ab)=\psi(a)\psi(b)$ for $f^{-1}=\psi\colon \mathbb{D}_6\to \mathrm{GL}$

Comment: Oh my God! It was so obvious that I didn't think of that. @Fakemistake

Comment: Also you don't necessarily have to find the bijection to show isomorphism. Existence of an isomorphism vs constructing the isomorphism. Like you specify several properties of both groups like abelian, has element of order 3, does not have element of order 6 etc. That cuts the isomorphism classes down. Just for future reference for similar problems where you haven't written $f$ already.

Comment: This is a good question I think. I recommend you the following to do that calculate the order of elements in $D_6$ and consider the order of element in $GL_2 (\mathbb Z)$ then you map(match) the elements whose have same order.